# Reading a line containing comma-separated floats from file using Fortran

Tags: io, fortran

I have a text file containing comma-separated numbers like so:

```
757.76019287, 759.72045898, 760.97259521, 763.45477295, 765.99475098, 770.2713623
```

It is not known how many of these numbers are present in this file; it varies but is limited to a few hundred numbers.

The objective is to:

1. Open this file (say, `customwav.txt`) and find out how many numbers are present in this file --> put them into an integer `n`.
2. Allocate memory for these numbers into an array --> I already have subroutines that do this for me.
3. Read the line of numbers into this allocated array.

What is the best way to do 1 and 3 in Fortran?

Comment: What did you try sofar, please add a MWE (minimal working example). This type of question (variable number of values on a line) has been asked before on this site, please search and I think you will find something.  The problem you are are addressing is not just a Forran90 problem but a general Fortran problem, for a broader audience please use the tag `Fortran`

Comment: If you are producing the input files, consider adding, as the first value of the data, the total number of values to read.

Comment: It seems like what you need is a CSV file reader. If so, have a look at this [Fortran CSV package](https://github.com/jacobwilliams/fortran-csv-module)

Comment: You need to give limits for some assumptions, say: is there a limit to the length of a line. If there is and there are multiple lines, then do a first pass counting the number of lines, number of commas in each line and max commas in a line.(num_commas + num_lines = num_values). Then rewind, allocate arrays and read the data. Alternatively, you know the file size so make a conservative guess. Given available memory, you can typically have a rough idea of what is required; A million lines and 10 million values covers a lot of possibilities, which is very little if you have 8gb memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your file only has one line, as it seems:

1. If you know the format of the numbers, you can do non-advancing I/O; e.g., if all numbers are floats which use 12 spaces, of which 8 are decimal places, and they are separated by a comma followed by a space, without a final comma & space after the last number:

   ```
       integer, parameter :: DP = selected_real_kind(15,300)
       real(kind=DP) :: x
       real(kind=DP), allocatable :: xall(:)
       integer :: u
       integer :: n
       character(len=2) :: c

       open(newunit=u, file='customwav.txt',status='old',action='read')

       n = 0
       do
         read(u, '(f12.8)', advance='no') x
         n = n + 1
         read(u, '(2a)', advance='no', eor=100) c
         if (c .ne. ', ') STOP 'unknown format'
       end do

   100 write(*,*) n
       allocate(xall(n))

       rewind(u)
       read(u, *) xall
       close(u)

       write(*,*) xall
   ```
2. If you don't know the format, or the format changes in non-regular ways, a lazy (and inefficient) method would be to try to read the whole array at one time.  The following dumb code tries this by increasing the size one by one, but you could do bisection.

   ```
   integer, parameter :: DP = selected_real_kind(15,300)
   integer, parameter :: MaxN = 1000
   real(kind=DP), dimension(MaxN) :: x
   integer :: u
   integer :: n
   integer :: error

   open(newunit=u, file='customwav.txt',status='old',action='read')

   error = 0
   n = 0
   do while (error.eq.0)
     read(u, *, iostat=error) x(1:n+1)
     if (error .eq. 0) then
        n = n + 1
        rewind(u)
     end if
   end do

   write(*,*) n

   rewind(u)
   read(u, *) x(1:n)
   close(u)

   write(*,*) x(1:n)
   ```
3. If non-Fortran tools are allowed, you can count the number of commas in the (single-line) file with the following shell command

   ```
   $ grep -o ',' customwav.txt | wc -l
   ```

   so the number of floats is that number possibly plus one (depending on the format).  For multi-line files, you can obtain the list of counts of commas per line with

   ```
   $ f=customwav.txt
   $ for lin in $(seq $(cat $f | wc -l))
   > do
   >   sed -n ${lin}'p' $f | grep -o ',' | wc -l
   > done
   ```

Answer (score 2):

My approach for an unknown file is to first open it using stream I/O, read 1 character at a time and count the occurrence of all characters in the file : count_characters(0:255).

This can tell you a lot about what to expect, such as:

```
LF indicates number of lines in file
CR indicates DOS file rather than unix file format
.  can indicate real numbers
,  can indicate csv file format
; / : can indicate other delimiters
presence of non-numeric characters indicates non-numeric information
E or e can indicate scientific format
/ or : can indicate date/time info
The count_<lf> + count_, is an estimate of numbers in the file.
```

The advantage of this approach is that it identifies possible unusual data to be recovered. It is probably best as a stand alone utility, as the interpretation can be difficult to code.

Answer (score 1):

OP tells us the file contains a few hundred real numbers, neatly separated by commas.  Here's a simple approach to reading those into an array of the right size. This is indifferent to the number of lines in the file.

First, declare an allocatable array, and an integer for handling the end of file which will occur later

```
real, dimension(:), allocatable :: numbers
integer :: ios
```

... allocate the array, with some overhead.  Yes, I'm just going to read however many numbers are in the file in one gulp, I'm not going to try to figure out how many there are.

```
allocate(numbers(1000))
```

... set every value to a guard value whose utility will be obvious later; this does assume that the file won't contain the chosen guard value

```
numbers  = -huge(1.0)
```

... read the numbers; I assume the file is already open on unit `inunit`

```
read(inunit,*,iostat=ios) numbers
```

... at this point `ios` has a non-zero value but for the simple case outlined in the question there's no need to do anything with it, we've been told that there are only a few hundred of them.  And finally

```
numbers = pack(numbers, numbers>-huge(1.0))
```

to reallocate `numbers` to the right size.

Comment: The problem with this approach is assuming the values in numbers, as both at the error and beyond they are processor dependent. I have different Fortran compilers which return a different result. For "read (line,*,iostat=iostat) (aa(i),i=1,k)" one compiler FTN95 returns I= value where error occurred (which is helpful), while another gFortran returns I=k+1 (which is not). gFortran also returns the value 0 where the error occurs, but FTN95 does not define this value. It is a problem that the error response is not defined. Another issue is being able to limit reads to 1 line/record of a file.